# How to use measured values as Input for a Simulink model?

Tags: matlab, simulation, simulink

I have a measurement series in csv format.
This measurement series includes two different RPM measurements amongst other things.
Also I have the cycle time of my measurement series.

In Simulink I do have a model describing motion of a differential driven vehicle.
Now I want to use my measured RPMs as an Input for my Simulink model. I also need to set the models cycle time to my measured time.

I already read something about this topic. Matlab suggests to use "From Workspace".

If I try to use my RPM values I receive following error: "Invalid matrix variable specified as workspace input in 'linkage_model/From Workspace'. The matrix data must be a real, double, have two dimensions, and at least two columns. The first column must contain time values and the remaining columns the data values.  Matrix values cannot be Inf or NaN."

So I added the elapsed time to a matrix like this measurements = [time_elapsed, rpm_right].
By doing so, I was able to start a run. However my data didn't look right at all. I connected a scope to the "From Workspace" block and discoverde just some linear function that didn't fit my measurements.

Now I don't really know how I could use measurement data as input for my differential drive model.

The "from spreadsheet" Block also does not work correctly.

Do anyone of you know a workaround for this?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show a [mcve]. It's impossible to replicate your issue without more details about what you've actually got set up, since the FromWorkspace block should work exactly as described with valid inputs